# Change the attributes of a character at a certain y,x location with python curses

Tags: python, curses

Lets say that the text "hello world" is printed out like so to a curses screen:

```
stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "hello world")
```

Now, lets say that I wanted the letter 'e' (y,x position 1,0) to have the attribute `A_BOLD` or `A_REVERSE`. How could I do this? Is there a function that just changes the attributes at a certain y,x position? I am using Python3.6 with curses (obviously)

EDIT: I tried using chgat, but it is not working as it should be. I used it like so:

```
stdscr.chgat(0, 1, curses.A_BOLD)
```

But this makes every single character after the x position has the attribute applied. I want only the character at the y,x position to be affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python curses wrapper has several variations of [**`chgat`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.chgat) with different parameter lists.  The one you should use is `window.chgat(`*y*, *x*, ***num***, *attr*`)`

If you want to move *back* to a given location, you would save the current location (which you obtain by [**`getyx`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.getyx), and then do a [**`move`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.move) to the saved location.

Comment: So this will move the cursor to that location. How do I move the cursor back to where it was before?

Answer (score 0):

```
curses.start_color()
curses.init_pair( 1, curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_WHITE)
curses.init_pair( 2, curses.COLOR_GREEN, curses.COLOR_WHITE)
curses.init_pair( 3, curses.COLOR_YELLOW, curses.COLOR_WHITE)

def pause(t):
    # update screen
    screen.refresh()

    time.sleep(t)

####################
screen.addstr(0, 0, "hello world", curses.color_pair(1))
pause(2)

screen.addstr(0, 1, "e", curses.color_pair(1) | curses.A_BOLD)
pause(2)

screen.addstr(4, 10, "hello world", curses.color_pair(1))
pause(2)

screen.addstr(4, 11, "e", curses.color_pair(2) | curses.A_BOLD)
pause(2)

screen.addstr(8, 20, "hello world", curses.color_pair(3) | curses.A_BOLD | curses.A_UNDERLINE)
pause(2)

screen.addstr(8, 21, "e", curses.color_pair(3))
pause(2)
```

Comment: abandoned this project, but thanks for the late response :)